# How to optimize this create/update/delete comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm with EF 6.

I have a list of currents item in the db, which I retrieve with:

```
ae_alignedPartners_olds = ctx.AE_AlignedPartners.AsNoTracking().ToList(); // list of List<AE_AlignedPartners>
```

Than, I retry the same objects from a JSON, with:

```
ae_alignedPartners_news = GetJSONListObjects(); // list of List<AE_AlignedPartners>
```

Than I'm making some comparisons (to see which I need to update, which I need to delete and which to create. That's the current code:

```
// intersection
var IDSIntersections = (from itemNew in ae_alignedPartners_news
                        join itemOld in ae_alignedPartners_olds on itemNew.ObjectID equals itemOld.ObjectID
                        select itemNew).Select(p => p.ObjectID).ToList();

// to update
IList<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_toUpdate = new List<AE_AlignedPartners>();
foreach (var item in IDSIntersections)
{
    var itemOld = ae_alignedPartners_olds.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
    var itemNew = ae_alignedPartners_news.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);

    if (itemOld.Field1 != itemNew.Field1 ||
        itemOld.Field2 != itemNew.Field2 ||
        itemOld.Field3 != itemNew.Field3 ||
        itemOld.Field4 != itemNew.Field4 ||
        itemOld.Field5 != itemNew.Field5 ||
        itemOld.Field6 != itemNew.Field6 ||
        itemOld.Field7 != itemNew.Field7 ||
        itemOld.Field8 != itemNew.Field8 ||
        itemOld.Field9 != itemNew.Field9)
    {
        itemOld.Field1 = itemNew.Field1;
        itemOld.Field2 = itemNew.Field2;
        itemOld.Field3 = itemNew.Field3;
        itemOld.Field4 = itemNew.Field4;
        itemOld.Field5 = itemNew.Field5;
        itemOld.Field6 = itemNew.Field6;
        itemOld.Field7 = itemNew.Field7;
        itemOld.Field8 = itemNew.Field8;
        itemOld.Field9 = itemNew.Field9;

        ae_alignedPartners_toUpdate.Add(itemOld);
    }
}

// to create
IList<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_toCreate = ae_alignedPartners_news.Where(p => !IDSIntersections.Contains(p.ObjectID)).ToList();

// to delete
IList<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_toDelete = ae_alignedPartners_olds.Where(p => !IDSIntersections.Contains(p.ObjectID)).ToList();
```

Which is faster enough for 1000~ records. Over 50k, it becomes very very slow.

What do you suggest to improve the whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out what's slow I suggest profiling or simply pausing the debugger 10 times to see where it stops most often (you can try that with your existing code). But here I could spot the problem immediately:

```
var itemOld = ae_alignedPartners_olds.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
var itemNew = ae_alignedPartners_news.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
```

This is scanning the entire list which is O(N). Together with the outer loop this becomes O(N^2).

The best solution would be to restructure your query so that these lookups are not necessary. It seems to me that the join already outputs the objects you need.

But you can also use a hash table to speed up the lookups.

```
var dict_ae_alignedPartners_olds = ae_alignedPartners_olds.ToDictionary(p => p.ObjectID);
var dict_ae_alignedPartners_news = ae_alignedPartners_news.ToDictionary(p => p.ObjectID);

foreach (var item in IDSIntersections)
{
    var itemOld = dict_ae_alignedPartners_olds[item];
    var itemNew = dict_ae_alignedPartners_news[item];
    //...
}
```

Comment: "It seems to me that the join already outputs the objects you need." it gives to me the interesection. But not if the elements itself (i.e. all fields) have been edited or not. I need to check that...

Comment: @markzzz you could say `select new { itemNew, oldItem }`. I personally would pull the loop into the query as well. `ae_alignedPartners_toUpdate = [join query here].Where(x => { ... }).Select(x => { ... }).ToList();`. This works better in my experience. Loops are harder to change, force side-effects, often it's more code, code is harder to move around and reuse.

Comment: I don't get what you are suggesting. Can you show to me a piece of code please?

Comment: To be honest it's too much work to transform that code. You can rewrite the entire loop as part of the LINQ query. Adding to the collection is Select, filtering is Where.